# Nested objects giving me trouble

Tags: reactjs

I can display "parent" data fine, but nested objects are giving me so much trouble. I'm getting the "Objects are not valid as a React child" error, but nothing I try from my research is working, such as using .map.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function GetWeather() {

  const [theForecast, setTheForecast] = useState('');

  const fullWeatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hell&appid=APIKEY';

  const getForecast = () => {
    axios.get(fullWeatherUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        setTheForecast(response.data);
      })
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getForecast();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="a8wrap p-2">
    <h2>City</h2>
    <p>{theForecast.name}</p>
    
    <h2>Weather</h2>
    <p>{theForecast.weather}</p>
    </section>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GetWeather />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

The JSON data:

```
{"coord":{"lon":10.9033,"lat":63.4455},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":283.54,"feels_like":281.6,"temp_min":282.59,"temp_max":284.15,"pressure":1032,"humidity":37},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":260},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1618674351,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1676,"country":"NO","sunrise":1618630806,"sunset":1618685480},"timezone":7200,"id":3136765,"name":"Hell","cod":200}
```

`theForecast.name` is fine, it displays the city name. Anything in the "top level" of the data works, but anything nested such as `theForecast.weather` or `theForecast.main` gives me that error. There's nothing that would make me happier after hours of trying to use .map in all different ways to see some way to have "Clear" pop up on the screen. I'd think `theForecast.weather.main` would work, but no. Am I getting undefined because I can't map over these for some reason, or is there an error in the way I'm fetching the data where React doesn't have the data, so it's undefined when trying to use map?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your JSON file, theWeather.weather is an *array* containing an object. So, when you're outputting theWeather.weather, you're outputting a full array. Arrays are objects. As your error message says, you can't output a bare object to JSX.

You need to pick an element of the array (there's only one now, so you'll need theWeather.weather[0]), but each element is also an object. Since objects still aren't acceptable outputs, you'll need to pick a property *of* that object (like theWeather.weather[0].description).

Comment: `{theForecast.weather[0].description}` spits out this: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Your explanation makes sense though.

Comment: That'll be because you're not dealing with what the component should look like before it gets the forecast from the server. getForecast takes time, and the component will render with its base case of `''` while it waits.